# iOS Check if remote file has updates before downloading

Tags: ios, nsxmlparser, initwithcontentsofurl

This is a two part question.
I am using NSXMLParser to download an RSS feed.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"linktorssxml"];
parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
[parser setDelegate:self];
[parser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:NO];
[parser parse];
```

I wondered if there is a way to simply read the header of the xml remotely and check the last update timestamp, so that I only need to run the parser code and actually pull the entire xml if there has been a change?

Further, as I said this is a two part question.
I have the same thought with a plist that is hosted externally. This is currently called as follows:-

```
_content = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"pathto.plist"]];
```

Again, is there a way of checking the header for last update time remotely, and thus only downloading the full file if there has been a change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but you need to use `NSURLConnection` or `NSURLSession` to download the data instead of asking `NSXMLParser` to do it for you.

You can get the HTTP headers (which probably include a last modified date) by using an `NSMutableURLRequest` to describe what you want. That has a method named `setHTTPMethod:`, and you can set the method to `HEAD`. Make the connection, get the headers, and decide what to do next.

Unless the XML is very large though, that's probably not the most effective approach. If the file has been modified, you'll just need to make a second network request to get it. Network requests are slow, so you should keep them to a minimum. In most cases you'd be better off using `NSURLConnection` or `NSURLSession` to just get the file. The response will include the HTTP headers, so you still get the date, and you can still decide whether or not to run the parser.

Comment: Many thanks for this. Your point about multiple requests was a concern I had of doing the check. Thanks for the advice. Out of interest, are NSURLConnection/NSURLSession any quicker at pulling the data than NSXMLParser? Or is there no difference?

Comment: No difference. The limit is how long it takes to set up a network connection plus how long it takes to transmit the data. Having `NSXMLParser` get the data is more convenient but not faster or slower.